# Volumes in calculus [Difference in Washers Techniques]

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The volume of solid of revolution that results when $ f(x)=x^2 + 1$, $g(x)=3-x^2$ revolved around $y=1$

What's the difference in the two solutions below?

Solution 1:

$$\pi \int_{-1}^{1} [1-g(x)]^2 - [1-f(x)]^2 \,dx $$
Solution 2:

$$\pi \int_{-1}^1 [g(x) - 1]^2 - [f(x) -1]^2 \,dx $$

Also, are the succeeding solutions the same as above ones?

Solution 1:
$$\pi \int_{-1}^1 [1-f(x)]^2 - [1-g(x)]^2 \,dx $$
Solution 2:
$$\pi \int_{-1}^1 [f(x) - 1]^2 - [g(x) -1]^2 \,dx $$

Comment: Within each pair of solutions 1 and 2, they are the same because $$[1-f(x)]^2 = [f(x)-1]^2$$

Conceptually though, since $f(x)\ge 1$ and $g(x)\ge1$ in that range $-1\le x\le 1$, the $[f(x)-1]^2$ form may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within each pair of solutions 1 and 2, they are the same because $$[1-f(x)]^2 = [f(x)-1]^2.$$

Conceptually though, since $f(x)\ge 1$ and $g(x)\ge1$ in that range $-1\le x\le 1$, the $[f(x)-1]^2$ form may be easier to understand.

---

The first pair of solutions is different from the second pair of solution, and the first pair is the correct one.

By comparing $1 \le f(x)\le g(x)$ in the range $-1\le x \le 1$, $f(x)$ is the "inner edge of the washers" and $g(x)$ is the "outer edge of the washers", hence the integrand should be

$$[g(x)-1]^2 - [f(x)-1]^2 = [1-g(x)]^2 - [1-f(x)]^2.$$